# setTimeout in call to API endpoint not returning values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm attempting to make a call to a separate endpoint within the Yelp API to extract business description info and hours of operation. I defined the initial POST route in Express and, using ejs, am able to display data when called for the first endpoint. I need to pass business IDs from an array created in my first endpoint to a call to the second, however I am getting `TooManyRequests` responses and therefore had to make use of `setTimeout`; this is where I'm running into problems

While `setTimeout` will allow me to console.log the returned results from the second call, it doesn't actually allow me to return any data to present to the page. No errors are thrown and I am not being returned `undefined`, further adding to my confusion.

I attempted to wrap `setTimeout` into an IIFE both inside and outside of my for-loop which yielded the same results as before. I briefly considered implementing Promises but was seeing if this could be accomplished solely using `setTimeout`. Not sure if I'm using the proper approach here but any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

app.js

```
express = require("express");
var app = express(); 
var path = require("path"); 
var yelp = require("yelp-fusion");
var request = require("request");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

let client = yelp.client("API_KEY_HID");

app.get("/", function(req,res){
res.render("landing");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  client.search({
  term: 'coffee',
  location: 'Oakland',
  limit: 10
}).then(response => {
    var businesses = response.jsonBody.businesses;
    var idArray = [];  
    var openHours;
    var id = businesses.forEach(el => {
    idArray.push(el.id); 
    });
for(var x = 0; x < businesses.length; x++){
    var delay = 1 * 1000;
    setTimeout(function(x){
        client.business(idArray[x]).then(response => {
        var hours = response.jsonBody.hours.map(el => {
            return el.open;
        });
        openHours = hours.map(lo => {
                return lo[x].start;
        }); 
        return openHours; 
        });  
    },delay*x,x)
}
res.render('search', {
    hour: openHours
});
}).catch(e => {
console.log(e);
});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: You are calling `res.render()` BEFORE your `setTimeout()` callbacks get called.  `setTimeout()` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  It calls its callback sometime in the future.  Meanwhile, the rest of your function continues to run.  So you call `res.render()` before `openHours` has any data in it.  It's not clear at all what you're trying to do with the series of delayed `setTimeout()` calls (why you have that).  Also, please fix the indentation of the code in your post to make it easier to read.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you. The purpose of ```setTimeout()``` is due to the fact that I was receiving ```tooManyRequest``` errors.

Comment: Oh, so  `client.business(idArray[x])` is the source of that error.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, any call using ```client.business```  will return nothing to the page if I use ```setTimeout```:  it will console.log the data only. I'm needing to take client Ids from the first endpoint at ```client.search``` and use these in ```client.business```. I believe as @Hadas Zeilberger pointed out, this has to do with promise resolution/execution.

Comment: Do you know if the problem is too many `client.business()` calls in flight at the same time (too many concurrent calls) or too many `client.business()` calls being made within a certain time period (rate limiting).  There are different fixes depending upon the actual limitation you're hitting.

Comment: The Yelp documentation states requests can be made for up to 50 businesses at a time (5k/daily max) which was what initially confused me as my limit is far below this (at 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of issues with your code.  For starters, `setTimeout()` is asynchronous and non-blocking.  That means your `for()` loop runs to completeion setting a bunch of timers, you call `res.render('search', {hour: openHours})` before ANY of the `setTimeout()` callbacks have been called and thus `openHours` is still empty.

Then, to solve the problem `TooManyRequests` error you're getting, you will have to redesign how you make requests and how you monitor when they are all done.  To do that optimally, you would have to know what your actual request limits are from the host you're requesting data from.  You need to know whether you are limited to a certain number of parallel requests in flight at the same time, limited to a certain number of requests within a certain time period (like 1 request/sec) or whether there is some other rule.

Without knowing how you're actually limited, you could design a serial request system (one request at a time with an adjustable delay between requests).  Chances are you could tune that to work with whatever limits your host is enforcing (unless you're just making too many total requests).  If you knew the actual rules, you could design more efficient code.  But, without knowing the rules, here's a tunable, serialized approach.

In addition, there were a number of other unclear portions of your code as it wasn't clear exactly what you were trying to accumulate in all your `setTimeout()` callbacks.  Each one was setting openHours to a new value (overwriting the previous value) so I couldn't tell exactly what you want that data to look like.  You will have to fill in that portion in the code below.

This serializes all your requests, one after another with a settable delay between them.  You can hopefully tune that to slow down your requests to something the host is OK with.

This code uses a `.reduce()` design pattern to serialize promises that works in any environment.  There are many other design patterns for serializing promise-base operations too.  If you have an ES7 environment, then async/await in a `for` loop can be a simple way to go too.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var yelp = require("yelp-fusion");
var request = require("request");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// utility delay function that returns a promise
function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(v), t);
    });
}

let client = yelp.client("API_KEY_HID");

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("landing");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    client.search({
        term: 'coffee',
        location: 'Oakland',
        limit: 10
    }).then(response => {
        var businesses = response.jsonBody.businesses;
        var idArray = businesses.map(el => el.id);

        // set your delay value here between reqeusts (here it is set to 500ms)
        const delayBetweenRequests = 500;

        return idArray.reduce((id, p, i) => {
            return p.then((array) => {
                return client.business(id).then(response => {
                    // not sure what you want to get out of this response and add to the array of openHours
                    // that we're accumulating
                    array.push(something here to add to the results);
                    // return delay promise so the next request will wait
                    return delay(delayBetweenRequests, array);
                });
            });
        }, Promise.resolve([])).then(openHours => {
            res.render('search', {hour: openHours});
        });

    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. Yes, I had a gut feeling my code had some issues that went deeper than the function not returning so I'm glad you pointed that out. As for ```tooManyRequests``` the Yelp documentation doesn't fully state *what* the QPS limit is, only that users will receive an error if they make too many so i'm assuming it's trial and error  and fine tuning the delay. I got my work cut out for now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reason you are not seeing any data:

the `then` function actually returns a `Promise`. [It resolves with the return value of the function that's passed into it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), which in this case is `openHours`.

To be more expansive, `client.business(id)` is a `Promise`. `client.business(id).then(resolvingFunction)` is *also* a `Promise`. As you know, 
 when `client.business(id)` resolves, it executes the function passed into `then`.
What you didn't know is that `client.business(id).then` *also needs to resolve*. The way you wrote it, it resolves with the value `openHours`. In order to execute, *it needs it's own `.then`*. It would need to be `client.business(id).then(...).then(openHours=>{do something with openHours})`. You don’t need two `then`s in this case, as long as instead of returning openHours in your `then`, you just do something with it. The smallest change possible to fix this issue would be moving `res.render` to the line that `return openHours` currently is. That would be kind of messy though. Alternatively you could do this with multiple promises or using `async`/`await` .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. As this is my first encounter with promises I'm having trouble understanding what's meant by the function needing it's own ***then***, as I thought this would be accomplished by ```client.businesses(idArray[x]).then(response)```.

Comment: I changed the answer to be more clear. Let me know if you need more clarification